# Probability of rolling a sum of $9$ with $6$ dice

Tags: probability, dice

Like in topic, you have 6 dice. You sum their values. What is the probability you get 9? How do I calculate it?

Comment: $$\frac{\text{number of outcomes where the sum of the dice is $9$}}{\text{total number of possible outcomes}}$$

Comment: But How Can I calculate number of outcomes?

Comment: I'm ashamed to admit that these sorts of problems always make me second-guess myself due to the following concern:  Suppose we have numbered the dice $1-6$.  Let's say in first scenario, all dice come up $3$ except die $\#6$.  In the second scenario, all dice come up $3$ except die $\#2$.  Are these scenarios distinct?  I.e. should the dice be considered "distinguishable"?  Would it even matter as long as we are consistent?--I.e. both the total number of possible outcomes *and* the total number of outcomes with a given hypothesis would increase, possibly proportionally.

Comment: @KajHansen: I'd say yes, since the question actually asks for the probability, rather than the number of ways.  If you didn't consider them distinguishable, the different ways wouldn't be equiprobable in general, and then there's no benefit to counting the number of ways (as far as eventually computing the probability is concerned).

Comment: For example, for two dice, we have 2 (probability is 2/36), 3 (3/36) for 3 dice we 3 (probability is 1/216), what if we have 6 dice and we're looking for 9 (x/46656)? How Can I calculate x?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the dice are six-sided and distinct (each of a different color, say).  Then there are $6^6$ possible outcomes in the sample space.  Let $x_k$ be the outcome on the $k$th die.  Then 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 9 \tag{1}$$
Equation 1 is an equation in the positive integers subject to the restriction that $x_k \leq 6$ for $1 \leq k \leq 6$.  Notice that if $x_k > 6$ for some $k$, then the sum is at least $7 + 5 = 12 > 9$, so we do not need to worry about that restriction (as Brian Tung demonstrated in his answer).

A particular solution to equation 1 corresponds to the insertion of addition signs in five of the eight spaces between successive ones in a row of nine ones.  For instance,
$$1 1 + 1 + 1 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 1$$
corresponds to the outcome $x_1 = 2$, $x_2 = 1$, $x_3 = 2$, $x_4 = 1$, $x_5 = 1$, and $x_6 = 2$, while 
$$1 1 1 + 1 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1$$
corresponds to the outcome $x_1 = 3$, $x_2 = 2$, $x_3 = x_4 = x_5 = x_6 = 1$. Hence, the number of solutions of equation 1 is the number of ways we can select five of the eight spaces between successive ones in a row of nine ones, which is $\binom{8}{5}$.  Hence, the probability of obtaining a sum of $9$ when six six-sided dice are thrown is 
$$\frac{\binom{8}{5}}{6^6}$$

Comment: In case others are not familiar with this technique: this is sometimes called the ["stars and bars"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Answer (score 0):

**General approach.** There aren't that many ways to get $9$ from six dice.  (I assume these are ordinary six-sided dice.)  Up to reordering, there are only the following three combinations:

$$
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4
$$

$$
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3
$$

$$
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2
$$

Calculate the number of ways to get each of these (including their reorderings), and divide by $6^6$ to obtain the probability.  You should obtain the same value as Matthew Conroy in his answer, hopefully with a lot less computation.  (Generating functions are a convenient way to obtain all of the probabilities at once, though.)

Comment: Just so you know: I deleted my answer. Cheers!

Comment: @MatthewConroy: Why?  It's a reasonable approach, and more general.  I would prefer it if the desired total were, say, $20$.

Comment: Oh, I just figured that if you went to the trouble to post a different solution that your solution was all that was needed.  Plus someone complained about some of my typesetting, so I just figured the easiest thing to do was delete it.  Cheers!

Comment: @MatthewConroy: Oh, well, it's certainly up to you, but I think multiple different answers is always better than a single answer.  (Witness N.F. Taussig's combinatoric symbol approach.)  And although I might quibble about the typesetting (I'm not sure, honestly), I wouldn't personally delete the answer because of that.  But again, it's ultimately up to you.